Why is the autocorrelation of an uncorrelated random noise process the dirac delta distribution?
I am reading Stochastic Methods by Gardiner and in the beginning of chapter 4 he motivates the rigorous interpretation of a Stochastic Differential equation by describing the properties of a "random noise" process. In particular, he writes (on page 80, or page 97 of the pdf):

The simple-minded Langevin equation that turns up most often can be written in the form
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = a(x, t) + b(x, t)\xi(t),$$
where $x$ is the variable of interest, $a(x, t)$ and $b(x, t)$ are certain known functions and $\xi(t)$ is the rapidly fluctuating random term. An idealised mathematical formulation of the concept of a "rapidly varying, highly irregular function" is that for $t\neq t'$, $\xi(t)$ and $\xi(t')$ are statistically independent. We also require $\langle\xi(t)\rangle =0$, since any non-zero mean can be absorbed into the definition of $a(x, t)$, and thus require that
$$\langle \xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle = \delta(t — t')$$
which satisfies the requirement of no correlation at different times and furthermore, has the rather pathological result that $\xi(t)$ has infinite variance.

My question is, how do we get $\langle \xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle = \delta(t — t')$?
I understand that if $\xi(t)$ is a white noise process, then the autocorrelation function and power spectral density are a Fourier transform pair, and in particular the autocorrelation function is $\delta(t)$. However, in this case, we are not explicitly saying that $\xi(t)$ is a white noise process. We are only assuming that $\xi(t)$ is temporally independent and has expectation $0$.
Aren't the above two assumptions already enough to show that the autocorrelation is $0$ for nonzero time deltas (i.e. if $t \neq t'$, $\langle \xi(t')\xi(t)\rangle = \langle \xi(t') \rangle \langle \xi(t) \rangle = 0$)?

Is that not from the definition of statistical independence?

Why does statistical independence imply $\langle \xi(t) \xi(t')\rangle = \delta(t - t')$? I'm not sure I follow. I believe it should be equal to the variance of $\xi(t)$ if $t=t'$ and $0$ otherwise. But there are no assumptions made about the variance.

So your question is why is the variance assumed to be one?

I think in the text the variance is assumed to be infinite right? Since $\delta(0) = \infty$? But yes, my question is why is the variance assumed to be $\delta(0)$?

But $\delta(0) = 1$. Infinite variance implies infinite power, which is an impossibility.
